# Opening socket to deliver email

Tags: php, sockets, smtp

I am doing a proof of concept work, which should be a custom SMTP server implementation. My question now is:

To which host shall I open the connection to, one of those in the MX records or directly to the root.tld?

I am using [fakeSMTP](http://www.axllent.org/code/fakesmtp/) as base and I wish to extend it a bit more. by actually delivering the email message.

Comment: what's the SMTP server listening on ?

Comment: default, port 25. And it is working perfectly as described in the description. (My phone on Wireless is able to pass the message to the fakeSMTP )

Comment: then you already know the answer to your own question.

Comment: basically I (think) I am, but I lack knowledge on who-does-what, in the messaging. I kinda miss the link between MDA.

Comment: i have no idea what your actully asking us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send an email with either custom implementation of SMTP server or with some other alien technology, one should do the following things within his code:

1. Lookup the MX records of the email host (everything after the '@' symbol)
2. Order them based on priority (to still be compatible with RFCs)
3. Loop over MXs and on successful connection `break` the iteration.
4. Write on opened connection the full information of the connection. The writing should be the same as when you are using telnet to send email messages, but one should omit the AUTH command.

This is what actually solved my problem. And as a short answer matching exactly what I've asked in the question:

You should look up the MX records of the email provider and open the connection to in on port 25 and write the message.

Answer (score 1):

> I am doing a proof of concept work

Then should at least have a basic understanding of the protocols. All internet protocols all well documented. In the case of SMTP, you should probably start with [RFC 2821](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt)